# How do proofs guarantee the structure of the statement?

Tags: proof-writing, propositional-calculus

In my math class, we are learning about direct proofs. Our lecturer tells us that you can prove an implication, by assuming the antecedent and then showing that the consequent must be true as well. But I am confused about two things. Namely

1. Where does this "rule" come from?
2. Why is it appropriate to deduce this relationship from this simple "checking"?

For (2), suppose that there is a true statement $P\implies Q$. A direct proof assumes $P$ and then shows $Q$ as well. But why does this infer specifically implication, rather than, $P \land Q$, since the only situation that was checked is shared by both those statements i.e. $P$ true and $Q$ true?

Comment: Because you don't know whether or not $P$ is true.  You only know that, if $P$ is true, then so is $Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the [Deduction Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) which is a theorem (or more properly, a "metatheorem", a theorem about theorems) from mathematical logic.

It establishes that if you have a formal proof of the implication $P\to Q$, then you can modify it to obtain a formal proof of $Q$ that starts from the additional assumption of $P$; and conversely, that if from the additional assumption of $P$ you can construct a formal proof of $Q$, then this proof can be used to construct a formal proof of $P\to Q$.

Thus, proving $P\to Q$ is equivalent to proving $Q$ from the additional assumption of $P$.

Comment: Thank you! I should maybe have stated clearer that, it's not the intuition that is confusing (for example, I understand that it's natural how implication "permits" (F,F) and (F,T), and doesn't "permit" (T,F) because we have clearly showed that (T,T) from (T,-)). My confusion is, what allows us to interpret truthiness and falsity in this way, and what in general are the parts of the system that makes it so. I assume it's more than "consistency", which is essentially what the truth table intuition seem to be appealing to.

Comment: @PrinceCay: First, I don't think you mean "truthiness", which, thanks to [Stephen Colbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness) means an assertion of belief that something is true based on intuition or perception without regards to evidence, logic, or facts. Second, I do not know what you mean by "what allows us to interpret truth[] and falsity in this way". What interpretation? (cont)

Comment: @PrinceCay (cont) A formal proof of a formula $R$ is a finite sequence of well-formed formulas, each of which is either an axiom, a previously proven formula, or derived from previous formulas using valid rules of inference (such as Modus Ponens), and has $R$ as its final term. The Deduction Theorem says that if you have a formal proof that starts from a set of assumptions $\Delta$ and ends in $P\to Q$, then, through a purely mechanical process, you can obtain a formal proof that starts from the set of assumptions $\Delta\cup\{P\}$ and ends in $Q$. (cont)

Comment: @PrinceCay (cont) and conversely, that if you have a formal proof that starts from the assumptions $\Delta\cup\{P\}$ and ends in $Q$, you can, through a purely mechanical process, obtain a formal proof that starts from the set of assumptions $\Delta$ and ends in $P\to Q$. Therefore, to obtain a proof of $P\to Q$, it  is enough to assume $P$ as an additional premise and prove $Q$. There is nothing about "truth" and "falsity" in the Deduction Theorem. This answers "where does this 'rule' come from?" From the Deduction Theorem; and "why is it appropriate" Because the DT tells you it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion

> If it is raining then the streets are wet.

is true

but

> It is raining and the streets are wet.

may or not be. What's the weather right now?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the relation between the implication $P \implies Q$ and the conjunction $P \wedge Q$ that you bring up at the end of your post, what you are observing is that
$$(P \wedge Q) \implies (P \implies Q)
$$
which you can verify easily using a truth table.

However, the other direction does not hold:
$$(P \implies Q) \, \, \, \not{\!\!\!\!\!\!\implies} (P \wedge Q)
$$
which you can also verify using a truth table: in the case that $P$ is false, the implication $P \implies Q$ is automatically true --- this is the [Famous Case of Vacuous Truth](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=vacuous+truth). But the conjunction $P \wedge Q$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

This proof technique is called a *conditional proof*:  You assume $P$, derive derive $Q$, and then point to that 'subproof' and say: Aha! so we have $P \to Q$.

OK, so you have 2 questions. If we assume $P$ and derive $Q$, why *can* we conclude with $P \to Q$ ... and why can we *not* conclude $P \land Q$?

Let's do them one at a time.

Why can we conclude $P \to Q$?

Intuitively/conceptually/inoformally this makes sense because the conditional proof shpows that *if* you assume $P$, *then* you can derive $Q$, or in short: If $P$ then $Q$ ... which we symbolize as $P \to Q$

More formally, what is going on here is this.  Suppose you are in the middle of a proof and you have a set of statements $\Gamma$. These statments are iether statements you started out with as premises, and/or statements that you have derived up to this point.  Now, suppose you make an assumption $P$, and show that you can derive $Q$. Of course, in the derivation of $Q$, you probably used $P$, but you could also have used statements from $\Gamma$ that you already had. So, what you really showed is that $Q$ is a logical consequence of the set of statements $\Gamma \cup P$. SO what that means is that it is impossible for all of the statements in $\Gamma \cup P$ to be true, while $Q$ is false.  OK, so now let's assume that all statements in $\Gamma$ are true. That means that it is impossible for $P$ to be true and $Q$ to be false. But since that is the only way for $P \to Q$ to be false, it must be the case that $P \to Q$ is true. In other words, if all statements in $\Gamma$ are true, then $P \to Q$ must be true as well.  And of course that is what you obtain thanks to the conditional proof:  you started with $\Gamma$, but you can now add $P \to Q$.

OK, and now: why can we *not* conclude $P \land Q$?

Again, first informally:  The conditional proof method *assumes* $P$. But that of course is not the same as saying that $P$ is in fact the case. Or maybe better put: if you are in the middle of a proof and have proven a bunch statements $\Gamma$, the assumption or $P$ is not seeing that $P$ is true, but rather it asks: "OK, so what would happen if $P$ *were* to be true in addition to all this?".  But that is different from saying that we have $P$ just because we got to $\Gamma$. And while $Q$ *would be* true *if* $P$ *were* to be true, that is also not the same as saying that we can conclude that $Q$we have shown $Q$ to be true, period.

A little more technically, let's demonstrate why concluding $P \land Q$ is a mistake. Well, consider this. Suppose we have the following statements:

$D \to L$, e.g. "If I am a dog, I have 4 legs"
$L \to \neg H$, e.g. "If I have 4 legs, I am not a human"

From this, we should be able to conclude $D \to \neg H$ ("if I am a dog, I am not a human") .. and we do this through a conditional proof: Let's assume that I I would be a dog: $D$. OK, then we can combine that with $D \to L$ to get $L$: I have 4 legs.  And then we can combine that with $L \to \neg H$ to get $\neg H$: I am not a human. So using the rule, we indeed get: $D \to \neg H$: "If I am a dog, then I am a human". All makes sense, right?

OK, but what if we were to be able to conclude $D \land C$?  Then suddenly we have conclude that I *am* a dog, and that I am *not* human!!  That should be wrong

And to do this really technically:  Does $D \land \neg H$ follows from $D \to L$ and $L \to \neg H$?  No, because when $D$ and $L$ are false, but $H$ is true, then   $D \to L$ and $L \to \neg H$ are both true, but $D \land \neg H$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

Arturo has already given the formal answer for why this method of proof is correct. Let me offer an informal explanation for why.

It helps to first consider the truth table of $P\to Q$:
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
P & Q & P\rightarrow Q \\ \hline
F & F & 1 \\
F & T & 1 \\
T & F & 0 \\
T & T & 1 
\end{array}
Now consider the implication

> If the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant) $\gamma$ is rational, then $\gamma+1$ is rational.

(It does not matter if you don't understand the definition of $\gamma$. For our purposes, it just a real number, approximately equal to $0.577$.)

The implication would be false in the situation that $\gamma$ is rational, and $\gamma+1$ is irrational. Otherwise, it would be true. Now, even the top mathematicians can't work out whether $\gamma$ is rational or not. Nevertheless, I claim that we can prove that the implication holds.

First, suppose that $\gamma$ is irrational. Then, $P=F$, and so $P\to Q$ holds, regardless of whether $\gamma+1$ is rational or not – that is, regardless of whether $Q$ is true or false.

Second, suppose that $\gamma$ is rational. Then, we can write $\gamma$ as $p/q$, where $p$ and $q$ are integers and $q\neq0$. Hence, $$\gamma+1=\frac{p}{q}+1=\frac{p}{q}+\frac{q}{q}=\frac{p+q}{q} \, ,$$
and so $\gamma+1$ must also be rational.

Thus, regardless of whether $\gamma$ is rational or irrational, we know that the implication is true.

Now notice that in our proof, we could have ignored the possibility that $\gamma$ is irrational. The reason is that this corresponds to the case $P=F$, and looking at the truth table, the implication $P\to Q$ always holds in this situation, regardless of what $Q$ is.

More generally, to prove $P\to Q$, we could try to verify it in two different cases: (i) in the situation that $P$ is false, and (ii) in the situation that $P$ is true. However, since $P\to Q$ must hold in case (i), we can shorten our proofs by solely focusing on case (ii). That is, we suppose that $P$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

> But why does this infer specifically implication, rather than, P∧Q, since the only situation that was checked is shared by both those statements i.e. P
> true and Q true?

Nowhere in the proof did we check/show that P is actually true: we merely assumed it.

Neither we did check/verify that Q is actually true: we *derived* Q *under the assumption of P*, in other words, our proof was merely that **P implies Q**, not that Q is true.

You can also think of it like this: we have proved that **if P is not false, then Q must be true**. After all, if P is actually false, then our statement $(P{\implies}Q)$ is not making any claim about Q's truth!

Yet another way to think of it is this: we have proved that **either P is false, or Q is true**.

Indeed, all three boldfaced statements are logically equivalent to one another. (To fully convince yourself of this, just compare their truth tables.)